# Access Number of Users in a chrome extension HTML

Tags: html, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension, and I am creating a website for it, that has info, and a way to test it. I would like to show the number of users currently, but have found no way to do this. It doesn't have to update every day, but if it updated weekly that would be great!
Also- I don't care if it is by a outside company rather than chrome itself. all that matters is that it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am planning to show something similar on my extension's site so I have googled around a bit recently. I found a repo (https://github.com/petasittek/chrome-web-store-stats) that parses information about extensions in the Chrome Web Store. It could be useful for you. I think I will end up just parsing the Webstore page for the user numbers everyday in save it to a database. My extension is also available for Firefox and I will do the same there then aggregate the results.

Comment: Thanks, ill look into it.